# Where is the job support in Play 2.0?

Tags: jobs, playframework-2.0

In [Play](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play_Framework) 1.0, we can define some jobs which will be executed in the background:

```
@OnApplicatonStart
@Every("1h")
public class DataJob extends Job {
    public void doJob() {
       // ...
    }
}
```

But I can't find it in Play 2.0. Do I miss something?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen, thanks for fixing the mistakes of my question.

Comment: Hy @Freewind have you got solution? if yes, please do tell me know as well.

Comment: @MuneebNasir See the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32972812/342235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the links in original accepted answer which posted by [JonasAnso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1254147/jonasanso)

To obtain the functionality of OnApplicationStart you can use Global onStart

- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.GlobalSettings
- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/play/GlobalSettings.html

Here you can schedule your actors using Akka.

- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAkka
- https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaAkka

Hope it helps.

Comment: It seems from Play 2.4, GlobalSettings is deprecated? What's the new solution?

Answer (score 6):

You could use the scheduler service in akka.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/java/scheduler.html

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/scheduler.html

Basically you create an actor that executes your logic if it receives a certain message.

Comment: I think this is not I'm looking for. The jobs don't need to be triggered by actions, they are just working in the background.

Comment: For example, how to use akka's scheduler to implement `@OnApplicatonStart`?

Answer (score 6):

For the acutal job part this seems to be the way in Java,

```
Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(
        Duration.create(0, MILLISECONDS),   // initial delay 
        Duration.create(5, MINUTES),        // run job every 5 minutes

        new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                ....
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaAkka for more details.