# Promise<Result> replace Job?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I can't find Job in 2.0. Have been replaced by Promise? Promise seems a little complicated.

Comment: Don't mistake unfamiliarity for complication.

Comment: The same with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339714/where-is-the-job-support-in-play2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Play 2.0 you use Akka to trigger asynchronous Jobs. See [the documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaAkka).