# How to implement a scheduled job at specific date in Play 2.0?

Tags: scala, akka, playframework-2.0

[Where is the job support in Play 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339714/where-is-the-job-support-in-play2)

I have read this thread and found the way to implement scheduled jobs **at intervals** using Global and Akka.

But still have no idea with a scheduled job **at a specifc date**, for example, a job executed once a day at midnight.

Play 2.0 doesn't support it? If not, what is the best way?

Answer (score 10):

You could use the Quartz library with the [CronTrigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/CronTrigger.html) to execute Jobs at a specific date/time. Have a look at their [tutorial](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06). Here is an example with a simple scheduler:

```
import java.util.Date

import org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob
import org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory
import org.quartz.Job
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext

import play.api.Application
import play.api.GlobalSettings
import play.api.Logger

object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  val scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();

  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Quarz scheduler starting...")

    scheduler.start();

    // define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
    val job = newJob(classOf[MyWorker]).withIdentity("job1", "group1").build();

    // Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 10 seconds
    val trigger = newTrigger()
      .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
      .startNow()
      .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
        .withIntervalInSeconds(10)
        .repeatForever())
      .build();

    // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

  }

  override def onStop(app: Application) {
    Logger.info("Quartz scheduler shutdown.")
    scheduler.shutdown();
  }

}

class MyWorker extends Job {
  def execute(ctxt: JobExecutionContext) {
    Logger.debug("Scheduled Job triggered at: " + new Date)
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect Quartz will be a better solution than anything built into Play2. For one, Quartz allow jobs to run in a cluster via a JdbcJobStore. This makes it easier to deploy jobs to a cluster of play servers.

Comment: I just published a tiny module to help integration of quartz with play2 : https://github.com/mchv/play2-quartz

Answer (score 3):

Try Deadline in Akka?

"Durations have a brother name Deadline, which is a class holding a representation of an absolute point in time,
and support deriving a duration from this by calculating the difference between now and the deadline."

Comment: It's not clear from your answer if you can use the Akka scheduler with a Deadline to make this happen.

Comment: @dyross Play 2.0 seems to only have `Duration` scheduling available by default so `Deadline` isn't directly accessible.