# Cron Job in play framework 2.0

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

How to schedule tasks by cron expressions in Play Framework 2.0?

Equivalent to Play 1's `@On("<enter cron expression here>")` annotation

Comment: I need documentation for version **2.0**, not **1.2**

Comment: I think this a real question. It does not really help that playframework's documentation is so shitty that everything ends being a question on stackoverflow!!

Comment: please look at this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339714/where-is-the-job-support-in-play-2-0

Answer (score 12):

In Play 2.0 job scheduling is done with Akka:

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaAkka see section **Scheduling asynchronous tasks**

You can also use Global object to perform your actions while the application start/stop

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaGlobal